# Matplotlib.finance not responding after downloading mplfinance in Terminal. Error: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'

Tags: matplotlib, mplfinance

I am trying to create a candlestick / OHLC graph in jupyter notebook using closing stock data extracted from Stooq. I tried several different things to try and install mplfinance to get the candlestick_ohc imported, and keep getting different error messages no matter what I try. Below are the different things I tried:

Installed this successfully using Python in Terminal: 
    'pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/archive/master.zip'

And this in Terminal, which worked: 
    'pip install mpl_finance'

## 1 When I try to type this into Terminal:

```
'from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc'
```

I get this error message: 
    'from: can't read /var/mail/mpl_finance'

And yes, I have also upgraded mplfinance as well.

## 2 I also tried downloading this in Jupyter Notebook:

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates'
```

And get this error message: 
    'No module named 'matplotlib.finance''

**My question is, why do I keep getting error messages for matplotlib.finance when I have installed it in the Terminal? What am I missing or doing wrong?**

Comment: (1) You cannot type python commands in your terminal. You would first need to start a python session; then you can use python commands. (2) `matplotlib.finance` does not exist any more. So you need to use `mpl_finance` (which is also what you have downloaded).

Comment: How do I start a Python session? Sorry so new to this all, this is probably so basic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version of matplotlib finance, along with documentation, here:

https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance

Install with:   `pip install --upgrade mplfinance`

NOTE: The package name no longer has the dash or underscore:
It is now mplfinance (not mpl-finance, nor mpl_finance)

Comment: please kindly have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789254/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mplfinance-errors-out-even-after-pip-st