# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mplfinance' | errors out even after pip stall mplfinance

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, mplfinance

Running this on my Jupyter notebook on my MacBook gives the following error:
[image]

```
import mplfinance 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5bae819ae7bb> in <module>
----> 1 import mplfinance as mpl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mplfinance'
```

---

But I have installed mplfinance and upgraded it too. I've done the following on my terminal:

```
~ pip3 install mplfinance
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: mplfinance in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.12.7a17)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mplfinance) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mplfinance) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (8.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.21.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas->mplfinance) (2021.1)
➜  ~ pip install mplfinance 
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: mplfinance in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.12.7a17)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mplfinance) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mplfinance) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (8.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.21.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas->mplfinance) (2021.1)
➜  ~ pip install --upgrade mplfinance
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: mplfinance in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.12.7a17)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mplfinance) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mplfinance) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.21.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (8.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas->mplfinance) (2021.1)
➜  ~
```

Restarted kernel, even restarted my laptop but I keep seeing this error. Would anyone here have an idea as to why I'm seeing the ModuleNotFoundError error despite having installed it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Main issue I see is you reference `anaconda` in your tags (maybe that's where Jupyter is installed?), but the `pip` commands are all referencing a system-level Python installation, i.e., not a Conda one.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is not related to mplfinance per se.  The most common (but not only) cause of "module not found" issues (regardless of the package, and assuming that the module *is* installed) is that the package or module is installed in one place, but python's import path is looking somewhere else.

This can happen if the package was installed globally, but python is running in a virtual environment (or vis versa).  It can also happen if, for example, if running `jupyter notebook` runs a different (other installed) version of python than the one in which the package was installed.

A few things you can do to diagnose the situation:

1. Are you running jupyter notebook in a virtual environment that is different from where mplfinance is installed? (from your trace above: `mplfinance in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`)
2. At the terminal prompt: `which jupyter <enter>`
   This will show you from where you are running `jupyter` which may give you an idea from where jupyter is running `ipython` which in turn will give you an idea from where `python` is running.  Is it the same place where mplfinance is installed?
3. Try importing mplfinance outside of jupyter.  For example, at the terminal prompt type: `python -c "import mplfinance;print(mplfinance.__file__)"`.  Does that work?
4. Before anything else:

   ```py
   import sys
   print(sys.path)
   print(sys.executable)
   ```

   The first print will tell you where python is looking to find packages.  The second will tell you from where jupyter is running python (which may not be the same python where mplfinance was installed).
5. Compare `pip --version` to `pip3 --version`
   This may also give you an idea if you have more than one version installed

---

Another, but much less common, cause of "module not found" is a bad install.  If so, this can often be fixed with: `pip uninstall <package>` followed by `pip install --no-cache-dir <package>`